# MAT-DATEPICKER dateFormat

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the code below to get the date in my firebase database.

```
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" placeholder="Input disabled" 
               disabled [(ngModel)] ="member.joineddate">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="members">
                 </mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #members disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
```

The date in the box displays correctly. But, firebase contains the whole date like: Nov 11, 2017 at 12:00:00AM +UTC. And that gets displayed in my view, however I need to display just 2017/11/11. I could not find the way to convert it to database itself. In return I should be comparing the date with today's date also, so finding it hard. 
Could anyone be of help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to display just 2017/11/11

Did you try [this](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) example from angular.io? It uses momentjs. You can choose any format [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) offers